# Is it possible to change the name of the "app" folder in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When using Rails to only write an API, the term "app" seems less appropriate than something like "api".  Is it possible to configure Rails to use a different folder besides "app" to load controllers, models, etc.?  Preferably, I'd like my frontend code(outside the Rails asset pipeline) to live in "app", so creating a symlink isn't a preferable solution.

Comment: you can do it, inside `config/application.rb` you can add something like this to autoload custom folders `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: @mr_sudaca That does not work for me.  Rails does not load any of the API code.  tried `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/api)`

Comment: I see what you're going for, but this is one of the strongest conventions in rails and if you break it, the next person who has to work on the project will be confused.

Comment: @JaredBeck That's a good point.  I think I'll not do that after all, though I'd still be curious if this convention is possible to break.

Comment: Changing that will probably also break IDEs and other Rails specific tools, maybe even Gems.

Comment: @Ravenstine you can just create a sub folder in "app" for the `API` we do this all the time for name spacing purposes. To avoid breaking `Autoload` our directory tree is simply "app/api/api"  and then everything below that starts with `module API; #class declarations; end`. You may have to add an inflection too so that `rails` does not look for `Api` instead of `API`.e.g. `ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) { |inflect| inflect.acronym 'API' }`

Comment: Calling something "application" doesn't mean it isn't an API. The term's used in the [OSI Layer Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) to refer to ["user software"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) that runs on computers as distinct from underlying hardware and lower-level protocols. An API is an "application layer" concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably get it working by adding some hacks and fixes here and there. And then it will break again with the next gem/tool/IDE/plugin/...

Rails is strongly based on conventions, the `app` directory is one of them. Leaving as it is will save you lots of troubles.

Comment: Yeah, I'm convinced that's the right answer.  I ended up leaving `app` as-is and moving my frontend app to a directory `frontend` at the same level.